# What should be the anti-particle for proton?

Tags: antimatter, protons

In alpha decay (electron emission), the particles emitted along with electron is anti-neutrino. On the other hand, the particles emitted by beta decay (positron emission), is neutrino. Neutrino and anti-neutrino are anti-particle pair. There is particle anti-particle pair for each particle. Even electron has a antiparticle - positron. So, what is the anti-particle for proton?

Comment: You seem to have a few concepts wrong: Alpha decay is the emission of a Helium nucleus (two proton, two neutron). Beta decay emits an electron and an anti-electron neutrino. Positron decay emits a positron and an electron neutrino. Finally, the anti-particle of a proton is simply the anti-proton, where all the quarks of the proton are replaced by anti-quarks.

Comment: Look up what quarks a proton is made of then an anti proton is the corresponding three anti quarks.

Comment: But in alpha decay a helium nucleus is emitted, not an electron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_decay

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient research effort.

Comment: @ACuriousMind  Really.  This question demonstrates *absolutely no* research effort, not merely *insufficient* research effort.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your question

> So, what is the anti-particle for proton?

The following visual guide from the blog article [Why Making Neutral Antimatter is Such A Big Deal!](http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/2010/11/22/why-making-neutral-antimatter/) is helpful in this regard:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's called the antiproton. You can literally google "proton antiparticle".